# Add meeting to calendar

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

When I open a *.ics file in Outlook on the Mac an email composition window opens and the file is an attachement to the email. How can I get Outlook to add the meeting to my calendar instead of attaching it to a new email?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, support for importing and synchronizing for iCal is not yet available in Outlook for Mac.

If you are using an Exchange account, as a workaround, it's suggested that you could configure your account in outlook for Windows and [import your .ics](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-calendars-into-outlook-8e8364e1-400e-4c0f-a573-fe76b5a2d379#:%7E:text=Import%20.ics%20or%20.vcs%20file) file. Then the calendar will be synced to Outlook for mac.
[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.